# install ioncube on windows server 2008 with plesk

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, plesk, ioncube

I have a problem install ioncube on windows plesk control panel.
I used the thread-safe version of PHP and download Windows VC9 (x86) ioncube.
I Put the Loader files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\ext`

I do Edit the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.ini` and before any other `zend_extension_ts` lines ensure that the following is included:

> zend_extension_ts = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll"

and Restart the IIS server software.

but not run ioncube. :(

Additional Information:

> Loader is at: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll
>
> Loader OS code:   win
>
> Loader architecture:  x86
>
> Loader word size: 32
>
> Loader PHP version:   5.2
>
> Loader thread safety: Yes
>
> Loader compiler:  VC6
>
> Loader version:   4.0r7
>
> File size is: 475136 bytes.
>
> MD5 sum is:   a82aa4dc4ce18ff62ea8faaca97a31be
>
> Loader file:  Download loader file
>
> Loader found in ini file: Yes
>
> OS extra security:    None
>
> PHPRC is: EMPTY
>
> INI DIR is:   EMPTY
>
> Additional INI files: (none)
>
> Server type is:   LOCAL
>
> PHP uname:    Windows NT EASYSOFT 6.1 build 7600
>
> Server word size is:  32
>
> Disabled functions:   EMPTY
>
> Writeable loader locations:   C:\inetpub\vhosts\E-touch.ir\httpdocs,
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\E-touch.ir\cgi-bin

Answer (score 0):

Find Solve
I do upgrade Plesk and running php in command line mode

php -c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.ini" -v

I using the cammand found Problem in php.ini.
When the problem was resolved. ioncube was Run. :D